SSIS - Insert data from CSV file into the table from multiple environments (local1, local2, local3)
I am trying to insert data from CSV file into same name table from multiple environments(local1, local2, local3).
I am a new SSIS. Please help me to solve this problem. thank You!

Easiest would be to create 3 different data flows 1 into each table (and source being the same of the .CSV).  If you have to repeat this for multiple different files or other things could look at making the destination more dynamic, but that gets complicated.
In data flow I believe you can have 1 source and 3 destinations?

Thanks Brad, I think I need to use the foreach Loop container, but don't know how to do it..

It does get complicated to for each just for 3 tables and 3 different connection strings.  If you dont have to repeat this for a lot of other tables (just these 3) it would be easier to just manually create 3 connection strings and 3 different data flow tasks.

Hi Brad, it should be more that 3 and will add other tables. I just added env tables and read environments and then added data flow task in the foreach loop containe, but got a error..
Execute SQL Task (create env. table) -> Execute SQL Task (Read Environments) -> Foreach loop container (Foreach ADO enumberator, ADO object source variable: env) with Data Flow Task
